# Fetching the first and last result from a query

Tags: mongodb

In order to further my understanding with MongoDB, I'm attempting to answer a list of queries in order to fetch data from a dataset which consists of football matches (EPL Dataset).

A typical match document is set out as follows

```
    { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60490eacf8ab7e3fb26e67ec"), 
    "Date" : ISODate("2018-08-10T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "HomeTeam" : "Man United", 
    "AwayTeam" : "Leicester", 
    "FTHG" : NumberInt(2), 
    "FTAG" : NumberInt(1), 
    "FTR" : "H", 
    "HTHG" : NumberInt(1), 
    "HTAG" : NumberInt(0), 
    "HTR" : "H", 
    "Referee" : "A Marriner", 
    "HS" : NumberInt(8), 
    "AS" : NumberInt(13), 
    "HST" : NumberInt(6), 
    "AST" : NumberInt(4), 
    "HF" : NumberInt(11), 
    "AF" : NumberInt(8), 
    "HC" : NumberInt(2), 
    "AC" : NumberInt(5), 
    "HY" : NumberInt(2), 
    "AY" : NumberInt(1), 
    "HR" : NumberInt(0), 
    "AR" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

However, I'm trying to write a query to answer the following:

`Which teams have the most and least shots in the season?`

Where the `HS` and `AS` fields are the home and away shots for a match.

In order to write this query, I believe I have to try and group `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam` in order to collect each football team as they may either be the home or away team for a given match.

Additionally, I need to somehow store their shots by grouping their `HS` OR `AS`, either one depends on whether the team was playing home or away that match (e.g: If they were the home team then group the `HS` value).

So far, I've managed to group the `HomeTeam` and used `$SUM` to collect all of the `HS` values, followed by a sort to display the largest value first and the smallest last.

```
db.epl.aggregate([

    {
        $group:
            {
                _id: "$HomeTeam",
                HomeScores: { $sum: "$HS" }
            }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            "HomeScores": -1
        }
    }

])
```

However, anything beyond this point I am lost on what to do in order to solve this query.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Example of a document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60490eacf8ab7e3fb26e67ec"), 
    "Date" : ISODate("2018-08-10T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "HomeTeam" : "Man United", 
    "AwayTeam" : "Leicester", 
    "FTHG" : 2, 
    "FTAG" : 1, 
    "FTR" : "H", 
    "HTHG" : 1, 
    "HTAG" : 0, 
    "HTR" : "H", 
    "Referee" : "A Marriner", 
    "HS" : 8, 
    "AS" : 13, 
    "HST" : 6, 
    "AST" : 4, 
    "HF" : 11, 
    "AF" : 8, 
    "HC" : 2, 
    "AC" : 5, 
    "HY" : 2, 
    "AY" : 1, 
    "HR" : 0, 
    "AR" : 0
}
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/

Comment: Thanks, so I'm aware of `$first` and `$last` however, how would I group together the data so that teams are grouped together based on whether they were an `HomeTeam` or `AwayTeam` for a given match?

Comment: Please post a sample data ,as I see the data contains type declaration above

Comment: I've added one at the bottom of the post as an edit